# Read DOC and DOCX files in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word

I'm trying to read Word files with C#. I just need the text from the word document.

I'm using NetOffice library. It works ok if there is Micorsoft Word installed on the machine, but throws  exception if the MS Word isn't installed.

Error: "Word.ApplicationNetOffice progId not found. Word.Application at NetOffice.COMObject.CreateFromProgId(String progId)"

I'm guessing that this doesn't work because NetOffice uses Interop for manipulating word files. Are there any open source libraries that can read DOC or DOCX files (or one library for DOC and one for DOCX)?

Comment: It is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Is there solution for this? I wasn't been able to find any open source library for reading DOC files.

Comment: I would be surprised if you found such a library, since DOC is a proprietary format.

Comment: @JohnSaunders https://npoi.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[OpenXML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) is available for free and supports .docx and other office 2007+ formats.

[Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/.net/word-component.aspx) is commercial, but does offer support for .doc files (among others).